# Logging out from facebook when using MVC 5 OWIN

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook-login, owin

I have an MVC 5 web app that has facebook authentication set up and working nicely. User clicks "Facebook" on the login page, signs in to Facebook and that authenticates with our web site. If the user logs out, the call to AuthenticationManager.SignOut() logs out of the web site correctly, but if the user then goes back to the login page and clicks "Facebook" again they are immediately signed in without having to sign in to facebook.

So my question is, how do I configure MVC 5 OWIN facebook login so that the user is signed out of facebook when they sign out of the web site, or to put it another way, prevent caching of the authentication for the next sign in. I don't want a users facebook login to be silently cached in case they are sharing a browser with other users.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I know to do this would be to tie an event to your log out button or link and use the [Facebook Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/) to actually perform the Facebook logout for you.

```
<a href="/Account/Logout" id="Logout">LogOut</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
      $("#Logout").on("click", function(e){
        if(confirm("This will also log you out of Facebook.  Proceed?")){
           FB.logout(function(response) {
           // Person is now logged out
           });
         }else{ 
            //do not allow the link to continue and sign our of your site.
            //This is optional and allows you to provide options
            e.PreventDefault();
         }
      });    
   });
</script>
```

You could actually use the confirm dialog to ask if they want to be signed out of Facebook as well. A confirm would mean yes, a not confirm would mean no, just sign me out of your site.  Again, using the SDK and a little bit of control logic should provide the results you need.

Comment: Thanks for this - I suspect this will indeed be the approach I need to go with. Problem is that the MVC / OWIN stuff takes care of the login process so the client is not logged in with the Facebook API. I suspect that FB.logout will require an access token - which the client won't have as it wasn't used to perform the login. Seems to me this problem is a pretty fundamental issue with the external login support in MVC (with MS/google login too) - IMHO "Login using facebook" doesn't make it clear that logging out leaves you logged in to facebook.

Comment: @fubaar  When you login with the Facebook API from the server side, the user will still need to login to Facebook as well so that they can approve permissions and so that Facebook knows what user id to send back to your application.  Server side or client side, log in with Facebook will log the user into Facebook and your application.

Comment: @fubaar - as to your second comment, this is how almost all oAuth providers work.  Try logging into FourSquare (for instance) with your social account.  Then log out, you will still be logged into Facebook and/or Twitter. :)

Comment: Thanks for following up on the second comment. I'm not arguing with the reality - that you are logged in to Facebook when you use it for SSO - I just don't think that's the way it is presented to the user and is a security risk on shared computers. "Use another service to log in" doesn't make it clear that you will remain logged in when you log out of the web site.

Comment: The point I was making about MVC / OWIN is that we're not currently using the client side javascript library to login, so therefore we wouldn't be able to use it for logout (as it wouldn't have the correct access tokens etc. available) without ditching the built in OWIN functionality.

Comment: @fubaar - I still dont think that is correct.  They are two separate things.  The fb.logout calls some Facebook server methods that would have access to the users Facebook cookie to initiate the logout.  We have an application now that uses a combination of the JS SDK and Server-Side OAuth (for longer lived access tokens) and they work together without issue.  I am moving toward using OWIN, and once I have a test project setup, I will verify that my assumption is correct or not :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. To do so would require being able to access cookies set by facebook.com which is explicitly forbidden for security reasons: you can only access cookies on your own domain. The login with Facebook is separate from your application. The user isn't truly logging into your site. They're logging into Facebook and Facebook is simply verifying the user identity with your site. If you're truly concerned you can put a message on your sign out page reminding them to sign out of Facebook as well.

You could *try* recreating Facebook's log out code (doing a post to the same action they use with the same data they send). But, I'm almost positive they'll be employing some sort of CSRF protection on that, so it probably won't work.

Comment: The user experience here is that they click a button under a title "Use another service to log in." (in the default MVC 5 login page). Then before they leave the site they click the "Logout" button. I don't think Joe User would expect to still be logged in to facebook, regardless of the technical reality. Seems to me that the external login support in MVC should at least offer a method to log out of the external login provider that doesn't involve nasty hacks to get the facebook access token. Google and MS "login providers" appear to be affected by this issue in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Saw this thread and wanted to add to it, to help the masses.

In the guidance, "Code! MVC 5 App with Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Google OAuth2 Sign-on" from Microsoft, it has the following section buried in it:

**Logging off your App and Logging in With Another Account**

If you log on to your app with Facebook, , and then log out and try to log in again with a different Facebook account (using the same browser), you will be immediately logged in to the previous Facebook account you used.  In order to use another account, you need to navigate to Facebook and log out at Facebook. The same rule applies to any other 3rd party authentication provider. Alternatively, you can log in with another account by using a different browser.

So this behavior is by design.

To learn more about OWIN, hear is some good reading:

- http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server
- http://brockallen.com/2014/01/09/a-primer-on-external-login-providers-social-logins-with-owinkatana-authentication-middleware/

Have more links to share, but drats, reputation is not high enough yet.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Its been two years and If OpenID Connect is used, then a solution exists as

```
// POST: /Account/LogOff
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
        return Redirect("/");
        //AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```